# Flash, ActionScript 3: How do you put this collection in a variable?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, variables, declaration

```
    public function MovePath(ob:MovieClip)
    {
        ob.x = 458;
        ob.y = -5;
        TweenMax.to(ob, 30, {bezierThrough:[{x:458, y:-5},{x:458, y:153}, {x:212, y:254}, {x:208, y:606},{x:208, y:1000}], ease:1});
    }
```

in the tweenmax there is a variable container "{x:458, y:-5},{x:458, y:153}, {x:212, y:254}, {x:208, y:606},{x:208, y:1000}"

but i want it to work like this:

```
    public function MovePath(ob:MovieClip,path)
    {
        ob.x = 458;
        ob.y = -5;
        TweenMax.to(ob, 30, {bezierThrough:[path], ease:1});
    }
```

i tried declaring the variable path as

```
var path = {x:458, y:-5},{x:458, y:153}, {x:212, y:254}, {x:208, y:606},{x:208, y:1000}
```

but with no succes
does anyone know how i can declare this variable proberly

thanks in advance
matthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = [{x:458, y:-5},{x:458, y:153}, {x:212, y:254}, {x:208, y:606},{x:208, y:1000}];
TweenMax.to(ob, 30, {bezierThrough:path, ease:1});
```

[] creates an array, so you are just creating an array of objects (with x and y properties).

Comment: never knuew where the "[]" brackets stouth for now i get it thanks